# Kafka node throws "TypeError: Client is not a constructor" using Node-RED

Tags: npm, apache-kafka, node-red, node-kafka

[Full flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOvct.png) I have installed the kafka node using

```
npm install -g node-red-contrib-kafka-node
```

But it throws

```
TypeError: Client is not a constructor
```

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

[kafka node properties settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJwxp.png)

Comment: The library you are using is pretty old. The latest release was about 3 years ago.

Comment: Can you please send me the command to install the latest one?

Answer (score 1):

[`node-red-contrib-kafka-node`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-red-contrib-kafka-node) is too old and its latest release was 3 years back. I would suggest you to make use of a more recent library. For example,

- [`node-red-contrib-kafka-node-fix`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-red-contrib-kafka-node-fix)
- [`node-red-contrib-kafka-node-latest`](https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-contrib-kafka-node-latest)